# docker visual studio ip address issues with .net core

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I am very new to Docker. And I created an empty .net core website with docker support. (Visual Studio 17 adds docker support files to the solution and you can run debug etc.)

[image]

Everything is ok... then when I run my website, it always opens in a different IP Address: for example http://172.20.52.{{random.ip.here}}/

Now I need to be able to open it in http://localhost:5000
But when I try to map the port 5000:80

[image]

Every tutorial I found states that all you need to do is map the port of your host to the container. At this point could it be an issue with my container network.
[image]
More information:
I am using Docker for Windows, with a windows host.
my networks on docker:
[image]

Comment: localhost seems to not work on windows containers. so to access it via the host you need to use the network ip address of the host computer

Comment: "localhost seems to not work on windows containers" +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do http://localhost:5000, the host port 5000 needs to map to container port 80. But in your container list screen shot, it's the host port 8028 mapping to container port 80. I think you should do http://localhost:8028 instead.